# Draugr Wight Lord disarmed me, can't find my weapon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was fighting the Draugr Wight Lord at Silverdrift Lair, and he used the Disarm shout on me and made me drop my Elven Bow. I didn't notice at the time because I switched to a sword right after that, but now that the fight is over I've searched all over the Word room and can't find my bow. Am I screwed? I thought Disarm was supposed to just disarm you, not make your weapon disappear.

Comment: I lost my legendary Daedrick greatsword the same way, just didn't show up on the ground. I just loaded a previous save because I didn't have the ebony to make another

Comment: I just had to reload many times or use a random weak weapon from the floor.I was in a dungeon with 20 of those shouting drougr at the same time so I used unrelenting force to see how they liked it.

Comment: It's a glitch. I had a harvest addon working and if I'd dropped the bow it would have been automagically picked up.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Disarm *does not* make your weapon disappear.

Unfortunately, Draugr usually live in the dark, and it can be *very* hard to find individual *anythings* in Skyrim, let alone in the dark crannies of its dungeons.

So your bow won't have simply *vanished*, and should be findable, if you want to devote the time and effort into locating it.

Realistically, you've got a few options:

- Load a previous save, fight the Draugr Wight again, and either avoid the disarm shout, or make sure you can pick up your bow immediately afterwards.
- Find your bow. If you want to do this, I'd suggest Candlelight / Magelight, and Unrelenting Force. Light up the area, and randomly try and blow everything around. You might knock your bow loose, as we humans are better at tracking moving things than picking out still objects.
- Mourn your bow and press on. There will be more Elven Bows down the road.

Comment: I've had some cases of an item passing through the floor/walls and being non-retrievable without using the console (either tcl or spawning a new one).

Comment: @Fambida definately had that happen to me before.  There was another time where we were fighting in an area with water that came up to the knees, finding my weapon there (2 daggers) was a PAIN!

Comment: I'll try doing this; I hadn't thought of using Unrelenting Force. Thank you.

Comment: I had one time where it seemed like *I* had passed through the floor, outside one of the side exits of Winterhold.  So, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a number of locations where something much smaller (i.e.: a bow) might slip through a crack.

Comment: I've had an item fall through the floor, then left the area and re-entered, and it had popped back up through the floor, so that may be worth trying.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using Unrelenting Force shout. That helped me spot my axe go sliding across the floor.

Answer (score 2):

In case of not finding your weapon during the night, press `T` and wait until you get sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is give up and make or find a new weapon. This happened to me while doing the Staff of Magnus mission and I just used one of the enemies weapons. I lost a sword but I had a spare. Also, Lydia was killed so you were lucky just to have lost your bow.