#  Why has the Draugr Deathlord in Valthume stolen my sword and my shield?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draugr Wight Lord disarmed me, can't find my weapon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42989/draugr-wight-lord-disarmed-me-cant-find-my-weapon)

Ok, so I started playing Skyrim. When I went into Valthume to find one of the shouts, I stumbled upon a Draugr Deathlord. When I started fighting him, he shouts, and my sword and my shield are gone! In the end I killed him with magic. When I checked his body though, I didn't see the weapons I was using. Does anybody know how I can recover them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deathlord used [Disarming Shout](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Disarm).  You weapon will be on the floor where you were disarmed, although it's possible it fell through the world per [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2242992) post.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like he used the Disarm Shout (ZUN HAAL VIIK) on you. Look around on the floor for your sword and shield.

Comment: Thx for your help dude! Didn't bother finding it though... The deathlord's weapon was stronger than mine so I got that! :D Btw do you know where I can find the Disarm shout to use it myself?

Comment: No prob. For the location, check out the link Sean C. posted, it lists the location for all the words of the shout.